# How to use exec method to start exe application and pass arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, command-line

It sounds very simple but I must be missing something here. I have a custom exe program, which is inside `C:\dummy\dummytest.exe` and I have a text file inside  `C:\text\test.txt` . All I want to do is start dummytest.exe by passing test.txt as argument in PHP. Here is what I tried:
    
    `$arg = "C:\text\test.txt"
    exec("C:\dummy\dummytest.exe".$arg);`
I tried with just single '\' also. And I tried 
    `exec("C:\dummy\dummytest.exe $arg");` but nothing seems to work. I get `C:\dummy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch file error.` 
When I go to command line manually and do 
    `C:\dummy\dummytest.exe test.txt` 
the application runs just fine. What am I missing here with exec?

Answer (score 2):

Use the "shell_exec" command instead.

```
shell_exec("[BAT or EXE-File] [Params]");
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

When using executables and parameters with paths you have to quote them.
So, an example would look like this:

```
echo nl2br(shell_exec("\"F:\\N3V Games\\Trainz Simulator 12\\compile_gs.bat\" \"F:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SHELL\\EBuLa.gs\""));
```

This example prints the output of a CMD-Window directly to the page.

If the executable is placed in the same directory like the php-file you can just run:

```
echo nl2br(shell_exec("compile_gs.bat EBuLa.gs"));
```

Comment: I tried shell_exec too. In my case, I tried shell_exec("C:\dummy\dummytest.exe C:\text\test.txt"); too woth no luck.

Comment: You have to escape the backslash.
Try: `shell_exec("C:\\dummy\\dummytest.exe C:\\text\\test.txt");`

Comment: I already tried that too..I tried using both single and double backslash.

Comment: I tried it, and it works finde on a windows machine.
`shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");`
Are your directory and filenames correct?

Comment: If I just execute dummytest.exe by using shell_exec("C:\dummy\dummytest.exe"); it works. But when I pass the argument (test.txt) thats where it fails.And I need to pass the text file as argument.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. So, if you give a path as paramter, you have to quote it.
`shell_exec("C:\\dummy\\dummytest.exe \"C:\\text\\test.txt\"");`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, and I just tried after seeing your comment. I am getting the same error "C:\dummy\dummytest.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch file.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to escape the command itself. Sorry. Look at the edited part of my text above.

Comment: Thank you, so much! That seems to solve the problem :-)